# How to catch __cxa_throw Programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, try-catch, throw, audiotoolbox

Some functions in AudioToolBox always throw __cxa_throw, at the same time the function such as ExtAudioFileDispose works well, the return value zero which is normal.
  When I want to use try {} catch(...) {} block catch this exception, but this doesn't work. While By All Exceptions Of Xcode, this exception could be caught.
  Here, just want to know what __cxa_throw is, and how to Programmatically catch it?

Comment: Were you ever able to find anything out? I'm running into situation with a library I'm trying to use. I'm thinking that getting at the exception it's throwing might let me see an error message that might be there.

Answer (score -1):

When I edit the scheme if you select Debug will execute.

[image]

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.